# JSON with special characters cannot load in Nativescript Angular

Tags: json, angular, nativescript

I want to `GET` following json file from server.

```
{
 "myKey": [{
            "code" : "RMB",
            "symbol" : "¥",
          }]
}
```

My Nativescript GET method as follows. If I remove the **"¥"** character, JSON can be load without any problem. With **"¥"** character, it goes to .catch((error: any) block. Please give some idea why this happens?
I am using "@angular/http" module for webservice calls

```
return this.http.get('mydomain/files/my.json')
     .map((response: Response) => {
         console.log("CurrencyDetails ", JSON.stringify(response));
         return response;
     })
     .catch((error: any) => {    
         let errorJson = JSON.stringify(error);
         console.log("Error ", errorJson);
         return Observable.of({'error': errorJson }); 
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine after escape the JSON

```
{
 "myKey": [{
            "code" : "RMB",
            "symbol" : "\u00A5",
          }]
}
```